# What is the implicit lifetime for the 1st argument when the 2nd argument is annotated with 'a?

Tags: rust, lifetime

While reading [Chapter 12.4](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-04-testing-the-librarys-functionality.html#writing-a-failing-test) of the Rust Book, I stumbled upon this function:

```rust
pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    vec![]
}
```

I understand why the code doesn't compile without the explicit lifetime annotation for the `contents` argument and the return value - the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html?highlight=lifetime#lifetime-elision) do not apply for functions with at least two borrowed arguments.

But I'm curious what's the implicit lifetime annotation for the `query` argument. I could think of two scenarios:

```rust
// Scenario 1
pub fn search<'a>(query: &'a str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    vec![]
}
```

```rust
// Scenario 2
pub fn search<'a, 'b>(query: &'b str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    vec![]
}
```

Both scenarios compile, so `query` gets either lifetime `'a` or `'b`. Which one is correct?

Comment: Given that the example function ignores the inputs you could also write:
`pub fn search<'a>(_query: &str, _contents: &str) -> Vec<&'a str>`
But that's definitely an unusual situation.

Comment: I snipped the function logic from my question body but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the `rustonomicon`, under [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html#lifetime-elision):

> Each elided lifetime in input position becomes a distinct lifetime parameter.

---

You can try assigning the function to a wrong type. Compiler will tell you the correct type of the function:

```rust
let x: () = search;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77e44b6bead28627dbb0eb794e1abc3c)

Result:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:17
  |
6 |     let x: () = search;
  |            --   ^^^^^^ expected `()`, found fn item
  |            |
  |            expected due to this
  |
  = note: expected unit type `()`
               found fn item `for<'r, 'a> fn(&'r str, &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {search}`
```

So, type of your function is:

```rust
for<'r, 'a> fn(&'r str, &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {search}
```

---

Also, if `query` also had lifetime `'a`, you should be able to do this:

```rust
pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    vec![query]
}
```

But this fails to compile because `query`'s lifetime is not `'a`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e6f01c70d387a65af9c51e0abf071e1)

Answer (score 3):

One way to think of it is that we're not 'giving' a lifetime with lifetime annotations, but describing how the lifetime of your return value relates to the lifetimes of your inputs.

Lifetimes already exist, but annotations let us set relations between them. As you never relate the lifetime of `query` to anything else in situation 2, we shouldn't really need to name it. Intuitively this makes sense as the most common case and the one that the compiler should (does) infer if you make no annotation on `query`.